# "Rocket elements" in bijections $f:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, infinite-combinatorics

Let $\mathbb{N}$ denote the set of non-negative integers. If $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ is a map, we set for $k\in \mathbb{N}$:

- $f^{(0)}(k) = k$, and
- $f^{(n+1)}(k) = f(f^{(n)}(k))$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

We say $r\in \mathbb{N}$ is a *rocket element of $f$* if $f^{(n)}(r) < f^{(n+1)}(r)$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and denote the set of all rocket elements of $f$ by $\text{Roc}(f)$.

If $A\subseteq \mathbb{N}$ we define the *upper density $\mu^+(A)$* of $A$ by $$\mu^+(A) = \limsup_{n\to\infty}\frac{|A\cap \{0,\ldots n\}|}{n+1}.$$

By $S_\mathbb{N}$ we denote the set of all bijections $f:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$.

**Question.** Is there $f\in S_\mathbb{N}$ such that $\mu^+(\text{Roc}(f)) = 1$?

**Bonus question.** If not, what is the value of $\sup\{\text{Roc}(f): f\in S_\mathbb{N}\}$?

(**Note.** Only the question needs to be answered for acceptance, but I am also keen to know about the "bonus question" if the answer cannot be directly inferred from the answer to the question.)

Comment: The beginning is just redefining powers in the monoid of self-maps of $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: And with a slight misuse of notation, too. Normally you'd write $f^n(k)$, I've only seen $f^{(n)}$ in the context of the $n$th derivative.

Comment: If you restrict to the wobbling group, that is, the group of permutations $f$ of $\mathbb{N}$ such that $\sup_n|f(n)-n|<\infty$, the trivial counterexample fails and there's no $f$ with the given condition, I think.

Comment: (Yet in the wobbling group the sup (of the bonus question) is $1$, by an easy argument.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Actually I would write $f^{[n]}(k)$.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Choose any infinite set $A\subseteq\mathbb N$ such that $\mu^+(A)=0$. Enumerate both $A$ and $B=\mathbb N\setminus A$ as 
\begin{align*}
A&=\{a_1<a_2< \dots < a_n < \dots\}\\
B&=\{b_1<b_2< \dots < b_n < \dots\}
\end{align*}
Then you can definite the function $f\colon\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$
\begin{align*}
f(b_k)&=b_{k+1}\\
f(a_1)&=b_1\\
f(a_{k+1})&=a_k
\end{align*}
for $k=1,2,\dots$. It is clear that $f$ is a bijection.

For this function $f$, the set of the rocket elements is either $B$ or $B\cup\{a_1\}$ and the asymptotic density of this set is equal to one.

Comment: Very nice construction, and nicely explained, thanks Martin!

Comment: The elevators in the Hilbert Hotel

Comment: Indeed, this argument shows that *any* infinite subset of $\Bbb N$ is Roc$(f)$ for some bijection $f$ (and of course, it's impossible for a nonempty finite subset to be Roc$(f)$ for any function $f$). Although we need to be a little careful, because $a_1$ might be in Roc$(f)$ with this construction.

Comment: @GregMartin Thanks for the comment. I missed the fact that $a_1$ might be in $\operatorname{Roc}(f)$.

Comment: Just to tie off the loose end, here's a modification of the construction: instead of listing $A$ in increasing order, choose *any* way of writing $A=\{a_1,a_2,\dots\}$ as a sequence, subject only to the restriction $a_1>b_1$. Then the bijection given in the construction definitely has Roc$(f)=B$.

Comment: @GregMartin, I think that [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/336117/rocket-elements-in-bijections-f-mathbbn-to-mathbbn#comment839931_336119) doesn't work if $B$ is a final segment.

Comment: @LSpice Aha, well spotted! And indeed (on further thought) no final segment $\{n,n+1,n+2,\dots\}$ with $n>1$ can be the rocket set of a bijection, because the preimage of $n$ would also be in the rocket set.

Comment: It seems that the classification is: a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ is a rocket set if and only if it is either empty, or infinite and co-infinite.

Answer (score 3):

You could also make the condition for $r$ to be a rocket element  be much stricter such as $$f^{(n+1)}(r) \gt f^n(r)^{f^n(r)!}$$ for all $n.$

Pick $A,B$ as before. Define $f$ on $A$ to satisfy this strong rocket condition. You will have a countable number of wildly increasing sequences. Split $B$ into a countable number of countable subsequences in a more or less explicit manner and use them to provide infinite front ends for each increasing sequence. These front ends might be strictly decreasing, but need not be.